# GitHub "Failed to authenticate to git remote"

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am a newbie in coding and I recently bought a **Chromebook** and tried to clone **my private repository of my GitHub account** on Microsoft Visual Studio Code and I faced this error:

[Failed to authenticate to Git remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX2SG.png)

And this is the terminal:

[remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myAccount/myRepository.git/'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP5Aq.png)

And it seems like [Visual Studio code cannot even find the repository when I type in the name of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guIk1.png). It is weird, because my Visual Code is synced with my GitHub account so it should find out my private repository.

I used to work on **my old laptop (Windows 10) and it worked, and it works fine even now!** I clone, commit, push, etc. and there is absolutely no problem.

However, I bought a [Chromebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromebook) recently which supports Linux (Beta), and installed Visual Studio code and tried to use GitHub.

I followed this instruction and had absolutely no error or any problem until **07:00**: *[GitHub on Visual Studio Code on a Chromebook and Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ggfV_e_7SU&list=PLfGT3BsHoYYxvXXQx-Ctq3KhxAgZNylL6&index=5)*

And **then I got the error** as I described.

This is what I have done:

- Updated and upgraded Linux
- Installed Python 3
- Installed Git
- Configured Git with my own username and useremail (double checked)
- Installed **gnome-keyring** and set my password
- Successfully logged in on GitHub in Microsoft Visual Studio Code

These are what I have done to solve this problem:

- I reinstalled Python, Git, and gnome-keyring several times.
- I formatted my Chromebook and tried the same several times from the scratch.

More information

- The repository is private.
- I tried cloning another private repository that I have made and it did not work.
- I tried cloning a random *public* repository and it *did work!!*
- As I said, it works perfectly with my old laptop (Windows 10).
- Same GitHub account, same repository.
- I did not change anything related to GitHub. I did not change the password, email address, username or whatever.
- I double-checked my spellings of the username and the email address. There is no doubt that I typed wrong username or email address.

I think it is related to not being able to access to GitHub from my Visual Studio code. Would it be the problem of gnome-keyring, or something else?

Comment: Yes, the underlying reason is probably the same and *[Fix for "fatal: Authentication failed for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/fix-for-fatal-authentication-failed-for)* is supposed to be the canonical question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix for "fatal: Authentication failed for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/fix-for-fatal-authentication-failed-for)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Oh my, YES it worked!! Thank you so much. it is solved by just installing an older version of Visual Code. I still wonder why it did not work, but at least it is solved. Thank you again!!