# Can’t connect to Bitbucket from Visual Studio Code

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

I'm having trouble to connect to Bitbucket from Visual Studio Code and I don't know why it's happening or how to fix it.
Everything was working just fine until today. After trying a Git pull from the Visual Studio terminal I get:

> remote: Invalid username or password 
> fatal: Authentication failed for "git url"

The thing is that if I use the Ubuntu terminal, everything works just fine. I can do fetch, pull, push, and pull request. It's just from the Visual Studio Code terminal that gives that error.

I've tried many of the solutions I found on the web, like trying to set back the URL with `git remote set-url origin` to no avail. I uninstalled Visual Studio Code and removed all settings and preferences, installed it again, but it is still not working.

Just to clarify as it's mentioned in many of the answers I found, I'm not using [two-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication), I'm on Ubuntu, and never changed user or password in Bitbucket.

What stumps me is that it works correctly from the terminal, just not from Visual Studio Code. I can keep working but it's really annoying.

Comment: A candidate for the canonical question is *[Fix for "fatal: Authentication failed for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it’s a bug in Visual Studio Code 1.62.2 that will be fixed in 1.62.3.

More [information is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/fix-for-fatal-authentication-failed-for).