# Git pull / push indefinitely hanging

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code and I'm trying to `git pull` from my GitHub repository as usual. It seems to be indefinitely hanging all of a sudden. In fact it looks like all commands that involve communicating with the repository are hanging. How can I go about triaging / fixing this?

My fix: I was on VSCode 1.62.1. I forced an update to 1.62.2 and it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Did you update to version 1.62.2 of Visual Studio Code? Then it could be due to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/) (though the symptoms do not match). In any case, what version are you using? Please add the information by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70014751/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: I was on 1.62.1. I forced an update to 1.62.2 and it fixed the issue for me. Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome. Are you sure it wasn't the other way around (I had to ***downgrade*** to 1.62.1 to work around the "remote: No anonymous write access. fatal: Authentication failed for XXX" problem)? Or is it two different problems, one requiring an upgrade and the other a downgrade? Or in other words, did the Visual Studio Code developers fix one problem, but create another?

Comment: No clue why it worked, but it was an upgrade not a downgrade. It's possible my issue was a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was on VSCode 1.62.1. I forced an update to 1.62.2 and it fixed the issue for me.