# gpg failed to sign the data after git commit -m 'sample text'

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, gnupg, netlify

I want to push my changes to GitHub in Git command, integrated terminal in VSC, and my profile is Bash, customized in ZSH. I'm deploying to Netlify through continuous deployment from Github.

Every time I do "git commit -m "xyz', I get error:

```
husky > pre-commit (node v14.17.5)
⚠ Some of your tasks use `git add` command. Please remove it from the config since all modifications made by tasks will be automatically added to the git commit index.

ℹ No staged files match any configured task.
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

We think it is an authentication issue, related to gpg key. We're able to run gpg2, but not able to sign in with key. We're trying to set the program to gpg2, and we have upgraded to gpg2, but it says it is already installed gpg. How to check what is gpg key?

We are not sure where to look/what to do now.

Previously I had problems with visibility of my contributions to Gihub, so I have gained Netlify permission to access my repository code. Netlify does this by installing the Netlify GitHub App on my Github account. Everything worked perfect, until I have updated my Macbook Air from Mojave to Big Sur v11. In the same time I had to update my terminal, so I screwed Homebrew upgrade. Yet, my profile is just Bash. Not sure about the last one, sorry!
Not least, but last, Netlify just announced Netlify API Authentication beta version to enable in my settings. I haven't enabled it yet, but I'm not sure if these are the source of my issue.

Comment: In any case, what ***versions*** of macOS v11 (Big Sur) and Visual Studio Code? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70033765/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Re *"After updating"*: The update to Visual Studio Code 1.62.2 caused many problems. A candidate for the canonical question is *[Fix for "fatal: Authentication failed for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).

Comment: What do you mean by *"After updating to macOS v11 (Big Sur) (Mac) in Visual Studio Code"*? That does not seem to make sense. Do you mean *"After* ***updating to Visual Studio Code*** *in macOS v11 (Big Sur) (Mac)"*? Or something else? Or in other words, what did you upgrade (and to what version)?