# Git synchronize changes works, but not push

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, synchronization, push, synchronize

Yesterday, I created a project locally, had a couple of commits, and published it without issues. Today I made two new commits and when I pushed I got this:

```
$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com/ImDino/todo_app_vue_v1.git': ImDino
Password for 'https://ImDino@github.com/ImDino/todo_app_vue_v1.git':
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/ImDino/todo_app_vue_v1.git/' not found
```

After this, I tried clicking the "synchronize changes-button" and it went smooth. I didn't have to login or anything. I double checked my repository page on the GitHub website, and the changes were there.

Also, I'm wondering why I'm asked to login at all. I'm already logged in through `gh login auth`.

Strange. I tried adding another change, committing that, and pushing went well with no login needed. I'm sure it's not because I entered my credentials previously, because when I first got the error I tried pushing twice and was asked to login both times.

Is there an explanation for all this?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio Code, a candidate for the canonical question for this particular problem caused by the update to Visual Studio Code to 1.62.2 in October/November 2021 is *[Fix for "fatal: Authentication failed for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).

Comment: Can you add some context to your question? E.g., what environment is "`git push`" used in? Inside Visual Studio Code, a raw terminal, or [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) (Windows)? What system (operating system, incl. version and distribution (if Linux))? What version of Git? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70038886/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).